# Sql developer tree shaped representation of explain plan

Tags: sql, tree, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

What exactly happens to the following Explain_Plan diagram [image]

It firsts Joins the two tables Products & Order_Items then the output is joined with Orders and then with the Customers.Am I right?if no please explain me, thank you very much.

---

EDIT:Also the query is:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       oi.amount, 
       oi.quantity, 
       p.name 
FROM   customers c 
       JOIN orders o 
         ON c.id = o.customer_id 
       JOIN order_items oi 
         ON o.id = oi.order_id 
       JOIN products p 
         ON oi.product_id = p.identifier 
WHERE  p.name LIKE '%DVD%' 
       AND oi.order_date BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '31/12/2000' 
       AND o.channel = 'Internet' 
ORDER  BY c.name;
```

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm#i16971). Do you not have any indexes? It looks like your query is filtering but it's still doing full scans of all the tables; which may be most efficient for what you're retreiving of course, but if you're looking at the plan then probably not. What issue are you having?

Comment: I want to figure out which is the plan tree I mean Orders are firstly joined with the output of Products & Order_Items and then with Customers as described or that Orders is joined with Customers and this output is joined with the output of Products & Order_Items?Also I don't have any indexes in this plan now I tried to create some plain Btree indexes where the tables are joined but still the same plan, what are your proposed indexes?

Comment: What you described in the question looks right. The indexes you need depend on your data and queries, and referential constraints etc. I'm no proposing anything, just seems odd to not have any. Ypu might need to gather statistics to have new indexes taken into account in your plan.

Comment: I 've updated my question with the query.I 've inserted indexes in oi.order_id,p.identifier,oi.product_id,o.id still the same the plan prefers `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.

Comment: Also I made indexes for the where statement still Table Full access is prefered,why is that?

Comment: I made some changes only indexes to products are been used and this when I am using both an index for name & identifier why is that ?